# How to create incremental horizontal scroll bar in android?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I would like to create a horizontal scroll bar which has the value varying between 1-8 with interval of 1 in android.And on moving to a particular point should indicate its value.Do we have any custom made approach to attain this.Thanks

Comment: by scrollbar, would you mean by any chance "SeekBar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is example.](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/SeekBar1.html)